# Get Autogenerated Guid- MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4

Does anyone happen to know if there is a way in the Entity Framework to return me the Guid of a just inserted row, assume the column is an guid which is auto Generated.

I am using MVC with Entity Framework. I am using Repository Method ADD(), the return type of the method is void.

Any one knows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StewieFG,

On adding the item, and hitting `SaveChanges()`, your object should now be populated with the value of the autogenrated column. Consider the example below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyEditViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        _myService.Insert(viewModel.Entity);
        _myService.SaveChanges();
        // we can query the column value for the autogenerated value now
        // i.e. viewModel.Entity.GuidIDColumn value etc..
        return this.RedirectToAction(x => x.Index());
    } else {
        PopulateViewModel(viewModel);
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

hope this helps